# Design pattern to develop a screen manager

Tags: java, design-patterns, user-interface

I'm trying to implement a screen manager and was wondering what is the best pattern to use. 
The screen manager has the following responsibilities :

1. manage all visible applications on the screen
2. hide/show applications
3. manage other Misc UI elements on screen
4. have a rules engine that defines if an application can be drawn on the screen or not.
5. manage screen space

There can potentially be more responsibilities

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Mediator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern), it may be applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say that an [Application Controller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/applicationController.html) pattern is what you're looking for. However, I'm not so sure based on what you've posted.

It's worth a look but I think you'll need some other components (Event Aggregator?) to go with it.